# Onclick textView android Dialer showing some additional number?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am creating phone dialer in android.i have one TextView onclick i am getting value from it. And i am trying put this number on dialer. But when i am trying to call Intent.Action_Dialer showing some additional value in it

**INPUT**-- 1234567890 // coming through textView
**OUTPUT**-- 6624531234567890 //showing on dialer
[This is code which i am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Gcb.png)

```
tvpMobile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String phone = tvpMobile.getText().toString().trim();// value of phone is- 1234567890
            Intent e = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            e.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
            e.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //e.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(e);
        }
   }
```

Comment: That really looks like what you'd get if you accidentally prepended an `Object#toString()` to your number, and `Uri.parse()`'d it. That code looks good, though. Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding your project?

Comment: yes.. i have done cleaning and rebuilding many time..even i tried with different phone also..but same result@MikeM.

Comment: I just tested your exact code on a `TextView` with "1234567890" as the text. It works just fine. You've got something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: can u help me to find that error

Comment: Not from just what you've posted. Are you calling `setText()` on that `TextView` anywhere in your code? Are you sure you're looking at the right code? What happens if you use `String phone = "1234567890";`?

Comment: yaa i found my error..thank u to pointing error in my program @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

Use this it may help to you.

```
btn_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + ed_call.getText().toString()));
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        return;
                    }
                    startActivity(callintent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();


                }
            }
        });
```

and Design Code

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_call"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_call"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Call" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
startActivity(callIntent):
```

I don't think you need the permission for this because user manually confirms for the call action.

Comment: Move your code inside onActivityCreated () if you are using this code in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + numberString + ""));
                    startActivity(intent);
```